# J2ME populate ChoiceGroup dynamically

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I am using LCDUI for my J2ME app. I have two Popup **ChoiceGroup** s. The 2nd CG's values should be dynamically populated based on the 1st CG's selection. I have tried the **setItemCommand** method but it doesn't work. How do I achieve the expected result. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the *setItemCommand*...

hm above sounds wrong way to me. *Selection* change events are intended to be handled with `setItemStateListener` / `itemStateChanged` pair not by item commands.

Also even with state listener there is a chance that second group will miss refresh on some buggy device. If that happens to you, consider something like forcing screen change with short-timed `Alert` as a workaround

Comment: Can't find such method :(, The ChoiceGroup has only setItemCommandListener

Comment: that's because you looked in the wrong place. Look in `Form` instead